# Folder as parameter in PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a script that pass every folder requested in a website as a parameter.

For example, if someone requests:

```
www.example.com/foo
```

...that will be redirected to the main index.php and passed as a parameter, getting the same result when requesting `www.example.com/index.php?foo`

Please note that the folder requested will be random so i can't predict the folder and put a php script there.

Should i handle all the 404 requests through HTACCESS? **Or there's a fancier solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but "www.example.com/index.php?foo" foo is an argument without value, so useless.
But if you want it "www.example.com/index.php?parameter=foo" 
You have to enable rewrite_mod on apache web server and use Url Rewriting in a .htaccess file.that an example which works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$   index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So example.com/abcd -> example.com/index.php?id=abcd

Comment: Actually 'foo' is not useless in the OP's example. In PHP at least, the parameter is available; but your solution of `parameter=foo` is better.